# How to use same component instance in multiple places on a page - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom component with it's custom `data()` object. I have a case, where i need to reuse the same component (calculator) on the main screen and in the footer:

```
<header>
  <Calculator/>
</header>

<footer>
  <Calculator/>
</footer>
```

I can use it without any problem, but they will be standalone instances of this Calculator component, for example: if i change one value on the first calc instance, it won't be reflected on second instance in a footer.

Is it possible to let's say "duplicate" this calc instance in a header and footer? Just like include in template engines.

Comment: You can change the value in the parent component and pass it through as a prop to the calculator component `<Calculator :someValue="yourParentValue" />`. Or use a store like Vuex, but that's a bit overkill I think.

Comment: Add props to both of your components. Accept as props an input or whatever value you are passing down. If its more complex, use vuex and make the state of your component global. This way, all components that rely on the information will update, no matter how many copies you have of your component.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066092/9556193) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right upfront:** Using databindings the way Frank mentioned it in the comment is probably the best way. If you want to reflect state to the other instance of your calculator, for example when data changes in one of them, you could simply use a 2 way data binding or an event to bubble the change back up to the parent and reflect it with a data binding back to the second instance. Since version 2.3 vue as the `sync` modifier for props to instantly turn properties into 2-way bindings as shown [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

The way you want your example to work is not possible as long as you are using vue templates. Vue templates get converted by the template compiler to render functions. Each tag gets passed to a `createElement` function, which **creates a new VNode**, so you'll always end up with two instances with two seperate states. If you however write the render functions yourself, you could create the calculator instance first and pass it twice to the render function - this should work in theory even though I've never tried it but it's not a great idea either way.

What I'm about to say now is just for fun, **please don't do it**:

If you really want to force the behavior of shared state between all calculator components you could [use an anti-pattern](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) and turn your calculator's data function into an object.

Comment: Thanks, making `data()` as object is what i needed for now. I'm not planning to use this component somewhere else. Also if Vue allows us to use `data()` as object, then why it's an anti pattern?

Comment: Because it potentially produces side-effects that you can easily lose track of in a larger app, also every single one of your calculator components will now always share the exact same state, you can't cherry pick ones that share state and other that don't. 2-way data bindings with reflected state in a parent component is a much cleaner solution and highly encouraged.

Comment: Here is an updated link to the anti-pattern: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function