# How to add directive to nested Vue components on render?

Tags: vue.js

How to add `v-b-tooltip.hover` directive to `myInput` and `myButton` without changing `myDiv` html? I've been trying to access them in render function but using api turns out not obvious.

**Updated**: added second component

```js
Vue.component('other-component', {
  template: "<div><b-form-input title='myInput'/><b-button title='myButton'>Button</b-button></div>"
})

var MyComponent = {
  render: function(createElement) {
    console.log(this.$slots.default.children);
    return createElement("div", this.$slots.default)
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component>
    <other-component />
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the slot vnode to achieve this.

```js
const MyComponent = {
  render(h) {
    let buttonVNode = this.$slots.default[0].children[2]
    buttonVNode.data.directives = [{
      name: 'b-tooltip',
      value: 'Tooltip Content!'
    }]
    return h('div', this.$slots.default)
  }
}
```

Example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sf5241do/).

If you want something more general such as find the vnode by their id attribute you may need to use recursive and check for each vnode children.

Comment: This might also help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066092/2438933

Comment: And for `b-form-input`?

Comment: @Feofilakt You can use the same method or you have other problems?

Comment: Thanks, it has worked. Somewhy I could not make it work in more complicated html hierarchy. Will try again.

Comment: @Feofilakt For complicate html hierarchy you may need a function like deep clone (you may not need to clone) to travel all vnodes and modify it as I commented above. Or update your question maybe I can help.

Comment: Its strange but in my application `this.$slots.default[0].children` is undefined

Comment: @Feofilakt Can you update the question for your new slot content?

Comment: I succeeded in reproducing conditions that bring to bug/feature I faced. There is no way to get access to nested objects. I updated the code snippet.

Comment: @Feofilakt I checked your new code, since it's a component template I don't think we can modify it.